# Android - Load PDF file without downloading or using google docs?

Tags: java, android, pdf-viewer

Is there any way to load PDF file from a server into a WebView, without downloading the PDF to the device or using google docs to open it?

I have been looking around but can not find any solution. I have also tried the code below ([Source](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/open-pdf-in-webview-android/)):

```
package com.pdfwebview;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webview;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        listener();
    }

    private void init() {
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("PDF");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        webview.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B534aayZ5j7Yc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl/view");
    }

        private void listener() {
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

but when changing the loadUrl link to my PDF file destination, the file doesn't show up either.

The required API is 15 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen good results in some apps I've worked on, using AndroidPdfViewer. It adds some MB to your final APK, but trust me it's worth it. It can render just about any pdf file and has great performance. You'll have to download the PDF to the device, but you can delete it afterwards.

It's currently the best way, and most compatible with older android versions, of loading pdf files without leaving the app.

You can read [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html) about the pros and cons of all the currently available solutions, and how AndroidPdfViewer is king among them :D

Comment: Thanks. I read about this library before but my question was remained, is it in any way legal to use this (since it's a library from GitHub) in an application that uses monetizing ads in every activity? Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: The lib is licensed under apache 2.0. There is no legal trouble as long as you provide a copy of the license somewhere in the app.

Read more about it here (specially number 4):
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't have enough knowledge of Licensing. What do you mean by "provide a copy of the license somewhere in the app" (which is also provided in Licensing, section 4a)? Does it mean i.e. in the app somewhere I provide that some part of my app is licensed under the Apache license and provide a link to the licensing, or is it more complicated?

Comment: See that LICENSE file right there? Just include that in your apk, along with another NOTICE file with the contents of the copyright, located at the bottom of that page.
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

Comment: Thank you. One last question. Should I only include the LICENSE and NOTICE files to my project and all is done? As I was reading here on how to add a license (https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html) it mentioned that I have to include <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" /> in the manifest and much more. Is this license adding explained in the given link, different from adding the MuPDF license to my app?

Comment: That's a different thing entirely, don't mind that. The 2 files should be enough, but if you wanna take extra precautions, include an option somewhere in your app where users can read all of that.
More info here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284773/what-to-keep-in-mind-when-releasing-an-app-which-uses-libraries-licensed-under-t

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/) but it'll open another activity to show pdf files. It has a very good performance and it is the most efficient way to display pdf files in Android.

If you want to view pdf inside webview then you can use something like [viewerjs](http://viewerjs.org/).

Comment: The MuPDF seem to be perfekt. However in their policy it written that the code that uses MuPDF should also be open source. I am a bit unsure if they mean the whole application code must be public or not, and have sent them a question about it.